# Determine if last action performed on each item was an install or a removal

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, normalization

I'm attempting to normalize a work database, currently one of the table has roughly 120 columns, and I'm building a new table that will correct many of the issues.

I'm attempting to figure out how to write a query that finds out which Panels are still installed.

Among the fields in the table, some of the most relevant are:

```
ActualCompleteDate
PanelID 
WorkType ("electrical install", "electrical removal")
```

I need to write a query that can isolate all installed Panels, and allow me to get their ID so I can use that query to migrate all necessary data to a new table. There are 12 other columns that need to be moved to the new table.

**EDIT**

The complete query based off of FuzzyTree's solution below:

```
SELECT  CHSRNumber,CableSize,CableLength,[CEA Type],CHSRLoc
        ,PanelID,ConnectorType,BreakerAmps,Voltage,[Status]
        ,InstallRDCLoc,Phase,UPS,BreakerType,ActualCompleteDate 
FROM (
    SELECT  CHSRNumber,CableSize,CableLength,[CEA Type],CHSRLoc
            ,PanelID,ConnectorType,BreakerAmps,Voltage,[Status]
            ,InstallRDCLoc,Phase,UPS,BreakerType,WorkType,[ActualCompleteDate]
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY PanelID 
                ORDER BY ActualCompleteDate DESC
            ) rn 
    FROM    [Facilities_Database].[Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] t1
) t1 
WHERE rn = 1 AND [WorkType] LIKE '%electric install%' 
    --AND (CableLength IS NOT NULL
    --  OR [CEA Type] IS NOT NULL 
    --  OR [CableSize] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY CHSRNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select all PanelIDs that have been installed and have not been removed after installation

```
select PanelID from (
    select PanelID,
    row_number() over (partition by PanelID order by ActualCompleteDate desc) rn,
    WorkType
    from mytable
) t1 where rn = 1 and WorkType = "electrical install"
```

or using not exists if your db doesn't support row_number()

```
select PanelID from mytable t1
where WorkType = "electrical install"
and not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.PanelID = t1.PanelID
    and t2.ActualCompleteDate > t1.ActualCompleteDate
    and t2.WorkType = "electrical removal"
)
```

Comment: This solution appears to work the best, the previous solution wouldn't run properly no matter what changes were made. For clarification, this should pick the correct option no matter how many times a Panel has been installed and removed at a specific location correct?

Comment: @Jdsfighter correct, this query will return all panelIds if the last action was an install regardless how many other actions there are for that panelId

Comment: @Jdsfighter fyi, corrected the 1st query. if your db supports row_number() it should be faster than the 2nd one

Comment: Luckily SQL Server does in fact support it. Thank you. It runs the query within milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

another method, a little easier to debug/extend:

```
select i.* from
(select
 PanelID, 
 max(ActualCompleteDate) as max_datei
from 
 table
where
 worktype = "electrical install"
group by
 PanelID) i left outer join
(select
 PanelID, 
 max(ActualCompleteDate) as max_dater 
from 
 table
where
 worktype = "electrical removal"
group by
 PanelID) r on 
i.panelid = r.panelid and
maxdatei > maxdater or 
maxdater is null
```